# Zeus server Url Rewriting

Tags: php, zeus

I am first time using zeus server , I dont how can I rewrite url

1. which file(with extension ) should I upload in the root folder for zeus
2. right now I am using Apache then .htaccess file is working but I have to shift my site on zeus server then it is not working right now my code in htaccess file is

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|js|robots\.txt)
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(js|css|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|swf|pdf)$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [L]
   ```

I want to use same redirecting on zeus server 
can any one Please know me which extension of file i should use and in which location(directory) i should put file,
and also please provide me  like same rewrite  code  for zeus server.

Comment: Have you read the Zeus manual on URL rewriting? The syntax is entirely different. You probably won't have much luck trying to get someone to rewrite your code for you on SO (although someone may prove me wrong.)

Answer (score 0):

naturally, as noted in the comments, a `.htaccess`-file with apache-specific instructions doesn't work on zeus so you'll have to do something different.

it's easy to find some tutorials that show how specific commands for apache translate to zeus-commands. the ones i want to highlight here are [this article on names.co.uk](http://www.names.co.uk/support/support_centre_home/528-zeus_rewrite_rules_user_guide.html) and [this post on drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/46508) where the second one shows up an important trouble with your question:

> There are a few things to note. **Zeus does not support** [QSA] or **REQUEST_FILENAME** or allow reading of server environment variables (you can write to them though..).

you'll have to [break the url down on your own](http://www.codem.com.au/streams/2010/web-development/zeus-and-crazy-url-rewriting.html) to get the different parts, so the rewrite-script will get a lot bigger than the one for apache.